# Force on a line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Say you have a rigid line of mass $m$ and length $\ell$ along the $x$ axis and you apply a constant force $f$ at one end in a direction that is always perpendicular to the line, starting in the $y$ direction. Assume there are no other external forces other than the applied force.

How would you find the position and rotation of the center of the line at time $t$ (or $dt$)? Would any parts of this line remain motionless? How does the answer change as you move the force towards the center of mass?

Comment: It would just rotate around its center and the center of mass will move in a circle, I believe. What do you think it will do? Well as it goes to center it should just move in a straight line. You should post what you think.

Comment: That seems intuitive. However, I want to know how to calculate this. All the examples I've found tend to deal with a fixed axis of rotation.

How would you calculate the motion of the center compared to the amount of spinning?

Comment: Think about it as two systems. One that has a torque applied to it and one that has continually changing force on its center mass. This is an interesting problem. I am more speculating than anything, hence the comment rather than answer.

Comment: So you could apply f=ma for the center and independently apply Torque=moment of inertia*angular acceleration to find the angle and thus position of the rest of the line? And the ratio of torque to moment inertia vs force to mass would more or less answer this?

Part of my intuition says that this is incorrect and you can't apply f=ma to the center of mass for some reason. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes to the first sentence. Not sure about the second question. I hope someone can answer this more explicitly, I would like to see what others approach are. Have you learned lagrangian mechanics?

Comment: Nope. This falls into that category?

Comment: Well almost any mechanics problem can be solved with lagrangian mechanics. It could be easier that way, but it is not necessary. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are the equations of motion:

1. You have the geometry so you know the mass moment of inertia about the center of mass to be $I_C=\frac{m}{12}\ell^2$
2. The applied force $f$ creates a torque about the center of mass equal to $\tau=\frac{\ell}{2}\,f$
3. The center of mass will accelerate by $a_C$ in the direction of $f$ with $$ m a_C = f $$
4. The body will accelerate rotationally by $\alpha$ with $$ \tau = I_C \alpha \bigg\} \frac{\ell}{2}\,f = \frac{m}{12} \ell^2 \alpha $$
5. Given the motion $$a_C = \frac{f}{m} \\ \alpha = \frac{6 f}{m \ell}$$ lets find if this corresponds to a rotation about a point.
6. If a point exists it will lie on the other side of the rod from where the force is applied, lets assume a distance $c$ from the center of mass. If the linear acceleration of that point is zero, but the rotation is not, then the linear acceleration of the center of mass would be $a_C = c\, \alpha$.
7. Find the point by equating $$ \frac{f}{m} = c \, \frac{6 f}{m \ell} \bigg\} c = \frac{\ell}{6} $$

FYI - The point of rotation is called a pole and the line of action of the force a polar. These show up in the [center of percussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_percussion) calculation. In your case, the point of the force $f$ is the point of percussion of the rod about the rotation point. You can reverse the situation and say that a point located at $c=\frac{\ell}{6}$ is the center of percussion of when rotating about the end point.

Comment: BTW: Any planar motion can be decomposed as an instantaneous rotation about a single point. In 3D, the instantaneous motion is a rotation about a line coupled with a translation along the line (called [Screw Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory)).